# How to find number of flags coming from console in Golang

Tags: go, flags

I'm passing argument from console. There are some flags too. Like:

```
go run test.go "-IP=10.10.10.10" "-db=kite" "-wv=45" "-cv=75" "A = value1" "B = value2" "C = 100" "D := ((A-B)/A)*C" "D ?"
```

Here, `-IP`, `-db`, `-wv`, `-wc` these four are flags and others are passing as normal argument as I know.

Number of flags can be variable.

How can I know how many flags are passed to my program. In this case `4` flags are passed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use the standard `flag` package to parse command-line flags, you can call the NFlag function to get the number of flags:

```
package main
import "fmt"
import "flag"

func main() {
        flag.Bool("a", true, "A value");
        flag.Bool("b", true, "B value");
        flag.Parse();

        fmt.Println(flag.NFlag())
}
```

Test:

```
$ go run test.go 
0
$ go run test.go -a
1
$ go run test.go -a -b
2
```

Comment: How to know which flag has been passed? i.e. how would I know if the flag `-a` has been passed or flag `-b` has been passed?